# Is there a way to reorder vertices?

Tags: vertices, topology

I tried to find a way to order vertices of my model from first image to look like second image but no success. Is there a way to do that automatically ?
[image: messy vertices]
[image: ordered vertices]
I tried retopology and align but no success. The file is [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9df9c36df635a42564827338a229c23f20240220101727/eac044?utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_05&utm_source=sendgrid&utm_medium=email&trk=TRN_TDL_05)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be another way but here is a try: Activate the addon called *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox*, then select your object and in the *N panel > 3D-Print  > Clean Up > Make Manifold*. In *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* (in the *Operator Box* set the *Max Angle* to 1°). Scale down 1/10th, apply the scale. In the *Data panel > Remesh > Voxel Remesh* with a *Voxel Size* of 0,05. Export the object as .obj. Open the freeware called *Instant Meshes*, open the object, choose your *Target Vertex Count* (for example 30,000), click on the first *Solve* button, then the second, then *Export Mesh > Extract Mesh* and *Save*. Result :

Before:

[image]

After (still improvable):

[image]

Comment: Wuauuuu! Fantastic result. I'll try it...

Comment: I don't know where is this "Scale down 1/10th, apply the scale."

Comment: press S then 0.1 then Ctrl A > Apply Scale

Comment: Why you are applying the scale 0.1 ? what is the purpose ?

Comment: So that the scale is 1:1:1 and that the Voxel Size fits the real scale of your object, by the way the Voxel Size may not be 0.1 exactly, choose the size that fits your need

Comment: I have no luck. Every time when I chose Remesh  Blender freeze and after 1 min it is closing.  I don't know what to do...:{

Comment: I succeded !!!  I'm not applying correctly scale...

Comment: I've edited my answer to leave some additional informations

Comment: Also if you have a lot of remesh to do, Quad Remesher seems to be the best tool but you have to pay: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CviZw41IbMg